# How do you run a Javascript file only without using an html and developer tool?

Tags: javascript

How do you run Javascript program like

```
function foo() {
  alert('foo');
}

foo();
```

without an html file like you can do in jsfiddle.  Can you do that in an editor?

Comment: You could use the **terminal** in the code editor.

Comment: Or install NodeJs and run the code from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Find a Javascript-console plugin for your text-editor or IDE
- Run your snippet from the console in your browser's developer tools
- [As Andy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919081/how-do-you-run-a-javascript-file-only-without-using-an-html-and-developer-tool#comment92748311_52919081), run it from a local NodeJS server

**EDIT:**
If you're on MacOS, this might help you even more:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-my-JavaScript-code-in-Sublime-Text-console